# Difference between parse_date=[0] and parse_date=True in pandas.read_csv

Tags: pandas

This code:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

data = "date,c1\n2012-07-31 02:00,1.1\n2012-07-31 02:15,2.2\n2012-07-31 02:30,3.3\n"

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),parse_dates=True).set_index(('date'))
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),parse_dates=[0] ).set_index(('date'))

print "df1:\n{index}".format(index=df1.index)
print "df2:\n{index}".format(index=df2.index)
```

returns:

```
df1:
array([2012-07-31 02:00, 2012-07-31 02:15, 2012-07-31 02:30], dtype=object)
df2:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2012-07-31 02:00:00, ..., 2012-07-31 02:30:00]
Length: 3, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Is this difference between df1 and df2 a bug,feature, or have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me. I created an [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1816) for this.

Note that by using the *index_col* argument it is possible to set the index.

```
In [15]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),parse_dates=[0], index_col=0)

In [15]: df.index
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2012-07-31 02:00:00, ..., 2012-07-31 02:30:00]
Length: 3, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Answer (score 2):

If `parse_dates=True`, the reader will attempt to parse the index as datetime (see documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html). And since you didn't set the index in the original call, it didn't try to parse it.

This will work:

```
In [237]: df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),parse_dates=True, index_col=0)

In [238]: df1
Out[238]: 
                      c1
date                    
2012-07-31 02:00:00  1.1
2012-07-31 02:15:00  2.2
2012-07-31 02:30:00  3.3

In [239]: df1.index
Out[239]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2012-07-31 02:00:00, ..., 2012-07-31 02:30:00]
Length: 3, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Comment: interesting, I think the documentation is saying different things.
"True -> try parsing all columns [1, 2, 3]" in [doc/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html)

Comment: looks like the docstring is inconsistent with the online pandas documentation. I'll fix it soon.